# Javascript navigation effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to build my own website, based off Google's Material Design principles, to better my design/UX skills.

I am currently working on effects for my navigation, I wondered what would be best to lower browser resource usage when viewing my web page.

> **Quick Example:**
>   When scrolling, without wrapping certain property changes within an `if`, does the browser (jQuery) attempt to make the property changes although they have already been made?

```
var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollPos >= 200) {
        if(!$('div.header').is('[style]')) { $('div.header').css('position','fixed'); };
    };
};
```

*compared to...*

```
var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollPos >= 200) {
        $('div.header').is('[style]')) { $('div.header').css('position','fixed');
    };
};
```

Full Code Example:

```
//scroll listener
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollPos >= 200) {
        if(!$('div.header').is('[style]')) { $('div.header').css('position','fixed'); };
        if(!$('div.nav').is('[style]')) { $('div.nav').css('padding','0'); };
        $('div.nav > ul > li, div.nav > ul > ul > li')
            .not('.faded')
            .css('display','none')
            .fadeIn(250)
            .addClass('faded')
            .css('display','inline-block');
        if(!$('div.header div.title').is('[style]')) {
            $('div.header div.title')
                .css('display','none')
                .children('h1')
                .css('display','none');
        }
    } else {
        if($('div.header').is('[style]')) { $('div.header').removeAttr('style'); };
        if($('div.header div.title').is('[style]')) { $('div.header div.title').removeAttr('style'); };
        if($('div.nav').is('[style]')) { $('div.nav').removeAttr('style'); };
        if($('div.nav li').hasCLass('faded')) { $('div.nav li').removeClass('faded'); };
        if($('div.nav li.nav-title').is('[style]')) {
            $('div.nav li.nav-title').fadeOut(250, function() {
                $('div.header div.title h1').fadeIn(250);
            });
        };
    };
});
```

*compared to...*

```
//scroll listener
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollPos >= 200) {
        $('div.header').css('position','fixed');
        $('div.nav').css('padding','0');
        $('div.nav > ul > li, div.nav > ul > ul > li')
            .not('.faded')
            .css('display','none')
            .fadeIn(250)
            .addClass('faded')
            .css('display','inline-block');
        $('div.header div.title')
            .css('display','none')
            .children('h1')
            .css('display','none');
    } else {
        $('div.header').css('position','static');
        $('div.header div.title').css('display','block');
        $('div.nav').removeAttr('style');
        $('div.nav li').removeClass('faded');
        $('div.nav li.nav-title').fadeOut(250, function() {
            $('div.header div.title h1').fadeIn(250);
        });
    };
});
```

Does either one make a difference in browser resource usage? Or is one incorrect?

Comment: I'd recommend you [edit] the post to include your *actual* real code, while expressing your concerns about browser resource usage - you can even include your html, css and javascript in an on-site executable snippet; you'll [get the best value out of Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436/23788) that way, since reviewers are always free to address any & all aspects of your code.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, having `scroll` handlers is not the best idea. Usually it kills performance.
- If you have no choise - use debounce-like function within - in 99% you do not need explict calls on every move.
- Don't use `$('smth')` within your handler. Save them to variables somewhere before. Do not look for them in your DOM tree on every scroll event.